# Session Variables Lost after ReDirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables, forms-authentication

I have an MVC site that is using membership providers for authenticating against multiple domains.

I am using SESSION to store the displayName of my user that I then display in my _Layout.cshtml

This all works perfectly on my localhost, but when I deploy my app to VM/Server the SESSION is null and i get Object not set to an instance of an object and the error points to the line in my layout page where i display the full username. This happens after session timeout and user requests a new page and are required to login again.

Here is my Login method:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    Session["UserName"] = "Unknown User";
    Logger.Instance.Info("Setting username to unknown user");
    var msg = string.Empty;
    var user = _userSvc.GetLoginUserData(model.Username, out msg);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) 
    {
        Logger.Instance.Info("getting user info but error returned: "+msg);
        ModelState.AddModelError("", msg);
        return View(model);
    }

    Logger.Instance.Info("User was found "+user.EMAIL);
    foreach (MembershipProvider provider in Membership.Providers)
    {

        var username = user.LEGACY_USERNAME;
        if (provider.Name == "ADENTMembershipProvider") username = user.ENT_USERNAME;
        try
        {
            Logger.Instance.Info("Authenticating user "+username+" to "+provider.Name);
            if (provider.ValidateUser(username, model.Password))
            {
               Session["UserName"] = user.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + user.LAST_NAME;
                Logger.Instance.Info("User authenticated " + Session["UserName"]);
                var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, // version
                user.ID.ToString(), // user name
                DateTime.Now, // created
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), // expires
                false, // persistent?
                user.ROLE // can be used to store roles
                );

                string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

                var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

                if (returnUrl != null && returnUrl != "/")
                {
                    Logger.Instance.Info("Redirecting user to " + returnUrl);
                    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }                           
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error("Error authenticating user " + username + " to " + provider.Name, ex); 
        }                
    }
    SynLogger.Instance.Info("User could not be authenticated " );
    // User was not authenticated in any of the AD
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt. The username or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
```

Here is the line in my layout that is causing the issue when session times out and user re-logs in:

```
<a href="#">Hello @Html.Raw(Session["UserName"].ToString())</a>
```

Not sure why it works on my development machine but not when I deploy to server.

Is there another way I can store the username other than SESSION so I can access it my layout page?

Comment: I forget if this works with Forms Auth, but have you tried 
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: you can use cookie rather than session. But the cookie also get expired after  certain time.

Comment: we are storing userId in the Identity.Name so we have that available for auditing otherwise that would work